# При повороте объекта по Y, повороты по X и Z он дальше понимает как одну команду

Tags: three.js, rotation

Столкнулась вот с чем: объект вытянут по оси Z. Повернула на 90град по Y, чтобы был виден в длину cube.rotation.y = -Math.PI/2;
Теперь не получается задать "клевок", "тангаж". Вращение и по X, и по Z он воспринимает как вращение вокруг своего "позвоночника" (впечатление, что в первом случае цепляется за новое положение, а во втором за начальное). Как такое скорректировать? В доке что-то есть про матрицы и кватернионы по части вращения, но без примеров сложно... (Поменять начальные координаты не годится, это упрощенная схема для работы с более сложными объектами)
https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/L743ma5k/1/

```
var camera, scene, renderer;
    var light;
  var cube;

init();
animate();

function init() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth /            window.innerHeight, 0.01, 20000 );
    camera.position.z = 1;
    camera.rotation.z = 0.1;        

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1.4, 7000);
    light.position.set(100, 0, 0);
    light.castShadow = true;
    light.shadowMapWidth = 204;
    light.shadowMapHeight = 204;
    scene.add(light);

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.1, 0.1, 0.6 );
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00} );
        cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    cube.rotation.y = -Math.PI/2;
        scene.add( cube );      

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );       
}   

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );   
        cube.rotation.z += Math.PI/2*0.01; 
    //cube.rotation.x += Math.PI/2*0.01; //то же,что и х
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Comment: Это так называемый Gimball Lock - особенность/недостаток Эйлеровой системы координат. Решается, например, переходом к кватернионам (когда вращение задается через относительные оси, а не абсолютные).

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, что недостаточно данных и я не совсем понял, в чем проблема, но тангаж, рысканье и крен вполне работают:

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;
var light;
var cube;

var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var time = 0;

init();
animate();

function init() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 20000);
  camera.position.set(0, 1, 2);
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);


  light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 7000);
  light.position.set(100, 0, 0);
  light.castShadow = true;
  light.shadowMapWidth = 204;
  light.shadowMapHeight = 204;
  scene.add(light);
  scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.4));

  var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.1, 0.1, 0.6);
  var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0x00ff00
  });
  cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(cube);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  time += clock.getDelta();
  cube.rotation.x = Math.cos(time) * THREE.Math.degToRad(10); // крен
  cube.rotation.y = Math.PI * 0.5 + Math.sin(time) * THREE.Math.degToRad(20); // рысканье
  cube.rotation.z = Math.sin(time * 2) * THREE.Math.degToRad(10); // тангаж
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```